# CXF WS-Trust service certificate configuration

Tags: cxf, client-certificates

Objective: Get information (using Apache CXF) from a third party (thus no control or access to the service backend) web service 
which use WS-Trust i.e. it authenticates the user using a Secure Token Service in this case with UsernameToken authentication.

I have spent a LONG time trying to learn about the WS-* security standards and at the same time trying out different frameworks and 
tools (Axis, Apache CXF, METRO with NetBeans, Microsoft .net, SoapUI plugin for Eclipse etc.) to connect to a specific service in 
the cloud. I am trying to develop a backend client that fetch information from the service. Apache CXF is attractive here 
because it seems to be the only Java framework which does not assume that everyone connecting to web services use clients deployed on a web application server.

The service providers have provided the necessary certificates and user credentials to connect to the service using STS. 
They have also provided a detailed user guide using NetBeans and METRO to create a web application that is deployed on a GlassFish server. 
I have followed this guide and managed to get data from the web service. Conclusion so far: The certificates are valid.

There are three certificates stored in a keystore (including chains):

1. webservice-encryption-certificate.cer (keystore alias: webservice-encryption)
2. token-signing-certificate.cer (keystore alias:
   token-signing)
3. token-encryption-certificate.cer (keystore alias: token-encryption)

=================================================================
**NetBeans configuration:**

*Service client:* 
Keystore -> token-signing-certificate.cer 
Truststore -> webservice-encryption-certificate.cer

*STS client:* 
  Truststore -> token-encryption-certificate.cer 
  Username -> user 
  Password -> xxx

=================================================================

THE BIG QUESTION: How can I make a similar configuration in CXF as in NetBeans?

I'm using CXF version: 3.0.2

"Translating" this to CXF gives me the follownig exception:

```
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/securitytokenservice}SecurityTokenService#{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/securitytokenservice}Trust13IssueAsync has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: The signature or decryption was invalid
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.createSoapFault(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:841)
```

Here is what i tried in CXF (amongst MANY other things):

```
MyService service = new MyService(); // Stub created from WSDL (real service name has been renamed to MyService)
MyServiceInterface port = service.getPort();

org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
Bus bus = ((EndpointImpl) client.getEndpoint()).getBus();
STSClient stsClient = new STSClient(bus);

stsClient.setWsdlLocation("https://login.some-domain.com/adfs/services/trust/mex"); // Web service is using ADFS 2.0 with MEX
stsClient.setServiceQName(new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/securitytokenservice", "SecurityTokenService"));
stsClient.setEndpointQName(new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/securitytokenservice", "UserNameWSTrustBinding_IWSTrust13Async"));

stsClient.setSendRenewing(false);

stsClient.getRequestContext().put("ws-security.sts.token.properties", "clientTruststore.properties");
stsClient.getRequestContext().put("ws-security.sts.token.username", "webservice-encryption"); // MOST LIKELY WRONG - WHERE DO I PUT THIS CERTIFICATE?

Map<String, Object> ctx = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
ctx.put("ws-security.sts.prefer-wsmex", true); // If set to false some policies will not be satisfied

ctx.put("ws-security.username", "user"); // REQUIRED OR FAIL WITH: No username available
ctx.put("ws-security.password", "xxx"); // REQUIRED OR FAIL: No username available

ctx.put("ws-security.encryption.properties", "clientTruststore.properties"); // REQUIRED OR FAIL WITH: A encryption username needs to be declared
ctx.put("ws-security.encryption.username", "token-encryption"); // REQUIRED OR FAIL WITH: A encryption username needs to be declared

ctx.put("ws-security.signature.properties", "clientTruststore.properties");
ctx.put("ws-security.signature.username", "token-signing");

ctx.put("ws-security.is-bsp-compliant", "false");
ctx.put("ws-security.sts.client", stsClient);

port.callSomething(createMyRequestObject());
```

I have tried to "decrypt" the meaning of the properties used in the code snippet above based on the following link (along many other tutorials and articles on the subject) to make sense in relation to WS-Trust and the certificates at hand.

http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/ws/security/SecurityConstants.html

I have tried all sorts of combinations using the constants but with no success.

How do I "pass" the service certificate (webservice-encryption) to the STS to tell it "this is the service that I want to use"?

By the way I have captured the traffic with Fiddler, and the request looks perfectly right compared to traffic captured with the NetBeans solution i.e. it contains timestamp, encrypted sections etc.

I KEEP GETTING "The signature or decryption was invalid"

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Hi, have you found sollution? I've run into similiar problem and I can't make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What does the response method from the STS look like? Is it an error message or does it look like the call succeeded? If it is an error message then it looks like you may be using the wrong certificates...you will need to enable logging on the service to figure out what the exact error is. If the call succeeded, then enable DEBUG logging on the client side and see what the problem is.

Colm.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem. Perhaps you must add JCE Unlimited Strength Policy jar files to JDK?